# Can I tell my generic, about that it should be only a function?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have error **Property 'apply' does not exist on type 'T[K]'** in my main function

```
const main = <T>(root: T) => <K extends keyof T>(method: K, ...args: any[]) => {
  root[method].apply(this, ...args);
};
```

On honest except as an example:

```
const main = <T>(root: T) => <K extends keyof T>(method: K, ...args: any[]) => {
  (<any>root[method]).apply(this, ...args);
};
```

**UPDATE**

I probably did not say so, but I meant this example ...

**UPDATE 2**

The second call with level3 and methods level4/5 (and only) - [works perfectly!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20ILevel2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20level2%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20level3%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20level4%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20level5%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20ILevel1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20level1%3A%20ILevel2%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20bigNestedObject%3A%20ILevel1%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20level1%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20level2%3A%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20console.log('foo'%2C%20args)%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20level3%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20level4%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20console.log('bar')%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20level5%3A%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20console.log('baz'%2C%20args)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20main%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20Function%20%7D%3E(root%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E(method%3A%20K%2C%20...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20root%5Bmethod%5D.apply(this%2C%20args%20)%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0Amain(bigNestedObject.level1)('level2'%2C%201%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204)%3B%0D%0Amain(bigNestedObject.level1.level3)('level4'%2C%201%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204)%3B)

If I add a level6 of another type (number) - [everything collapses :(](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20ILevel2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20level2%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20level3%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20level4%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20level5%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20level6%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20ILevel1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20level1%3A%20ILevel2%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20bigNestedObject%3A%20ILevel1%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20level1%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20level2%3A%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20console.log('foo'%2C%20args)%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20level3%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20level4%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20console.log('bar')%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20level5%3A%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20console.log('baz'%2C%20args)%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20level6%3A%204%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20main%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20Function%20%7D%3E(root%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E(method%3A%20K%2C%20...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20root%5Bmethod%5D.apply(this%2C%20args%20)%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0Amain(bigNestedObject.level1)('level2'%2C%201%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204)%3B%0D%0Amain(bigNestedObject.level1.level3)('level4'%2C%201%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204)%3B)

And it is very interesting why the first call all the time error?

In this case, if you make RUN - everything works result is 'foo' and 'bar', but the compiler typescript produces an error

Comment: I don't think that you need a generic function at all. It seems that what you're looking for is very specific. Is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: The following is obtained.
In the new example, UPDATE 2

Comment: Your structure is very specific. It makes no sense to make any solution generic. You will end up working way too much and will end up with a solution that is hard to understand and which will probably contain more code than needed and will also perform worse than a specific solution. I highly advise you to abandon the idea.

Comment: Unfortunately I got inherited this code and I want to do it typed. But maybe it really needs a rethinking.

I thought that if it was possible to put next to another condition, across operator & something like 
`<K extends keyof T && T[K]: Function>(method: K, ...args: any[])`
But apparently it's not obvious
Thank you

Comment: You can make it typed, but you don't need to make it generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
const main = <T extends { [key: string]: Function }>(root: T) => <K extends keyof T>(method: K, ...args: any[]) => {
    root[method].apply(this, args);
};
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20main%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20Function%20%7D%3E(root%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E(method%3A%20K%2C%20...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20root%5Bmethod%5D.apply(this%2C%20args)%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B))

Notice that [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) expects an array as its second argument so you shouldn't be using the spread operator.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I responded with an update (stackoverflow does not allow long links to be inserted in comments )